# vscode beautify remove custom space format

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I have aligned the variables in javascript like this

```
$scope.test1               = [];
$scope.other_thing         = [];
$scope.dropped_other_thing = [];
$scope.aaaaaa              = [];
$scope.validDates          = true;
```

when I apply the integrated formatted (beautify) for format with CTRL+ALT+F
change the code to this:

```
$scope.test1 = [];
$scope.other_thing = [];
$scope.dropped_other_thing = [];
$scope.aaaaaa = [];
$scope.validDates = true;
```

I want to preserve the original format for this situations but i cannot figure out how.

Comment: Take a look at the [Better Align](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wwm.better-align) plugin.

Comment: i'm using Better Align for formatting the first. but that only work for the vertical align based in colon, assignment and arrows. After that i have to apply the beautify to fix other format errors, like tab to spaces, brackets, etc.. and that broke the alignment from better align

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem possible without a plugin. [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) are all the possible settings.

Comment: but what plugin?? i have beautify from HookyQR that extend the properties of the internal formatter but even with this i don't see any option for tho something like this.